# removeClass does't work with $(this).attr('class') but $(this).attr('id')

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

I have this problem as reducing the size of my jQuery code. Basic function is to validate a form, if empty `addClass('highlight')` or `removeClass('highlight')`. It works fine if I use `$(this).attr('id')`, but when I tried to make it neat and changed to `$(this).attr('class')`, `removeClass('highlight')` stop working. Only thing I noticed is there are three `.text` `class`, I can't work out the reason. Please help.

Problem code: http://jsfiddle.net/designpromote/GRG2J/
Working code ($(this).attr('id')): http://jsfiddle.net/designpromote/GRG2J/4/ or /3/ (without switch)

I use `switch{}` because I need to validate different type of input.

The code is list as below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$('#myform :input').blur(function() {
    switch($(this).attr('class')) {
        case  'text': 
            if($(this).val() == "") { console.log($(this),  $(this).val()); $(this).addClass('highlight');}
            else {console.log($(this), $(this).val()); $(this).removeClass('highlight');}
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
});
 })
 </script>
 <style>
.highlight {
border: 2px solid red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">
<input type='text' name='business' id='business' class='text'><br>
<input type='text' name='address' id='address' class='text'><br>
<input type='text' name='city', id='city' class='text'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use data attribute to store field 'type'

http://jsfiddle.net/GRG2J/8/

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type='text' name='business' id='business' data-type='text'><br>
    <input type='text' name='address' id='address' data-type='text'><br>
    <input type='text' name='city', id='city' data-type='text'>
    </form>

$(function() {
    $('#myform').on('blur', ':input', function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            val = $this.val();
        switch($this.data('type')) {
            case  'text': 
                $this.toggleClass('highlight', !val);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    })
})
```

And run any js minifier for production

```
$(function(){$("#myform").on("blur",":input",function(){var a=$(this),b=a.val();switch(a.data("type")){case"text":a.toggleClass("highlight",!b);break;default:break}})});
```

Comment: Would you agree, that using the *switch* statement in the code makes only sense if it handles the highlighting of more than one type?

Comment: @line-o: Absolutely. Even in this case I'd prefer to have a hash of error classes for each type rather than switch. `{text: 'highlight', whatever: 'another-highlight', etc}`

Comment: tks, i was thinking to use id or name, but you showed me a new way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The function would return all the classes you have, thereby returning `text highlight` which is not one of your options. You may want to use the function `hasClass` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/GRG2J/6/

Edit: I just realized you mentioned that you have multiple classes and therefore use a `switch`, this may pose a problem with your current implementation because of the fact that your `highlight` class is added in addition to the `text` class. This also explains why the ID would work because you can only assign one ID per element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's true, after addClass('highlight'), $(this).attr('class') would be 'text highlight', but they are look for 'text' in the code, it would cause the problem i mentioned. It took me about 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

This solution may be verbose but easier to maintain next month.

```
$(function() {
  var theClass = 'highlight';
  $('#myform .text').blur(function() {
    // set meaningful variables
    var element = $(this)
      , isEmpty = (element.val() == '')
      , isHighlighted = element.hasClass(theClass)
      ;
    // perform action
    if (isEmpty && !isHighlighted) element.addClass(theClass);
    if (!isEmpty && isHighlighted) element.removeClass(theClass);
  });
});
```